# Problem sending Postman request to a json server

Tags: android, json, rest, server, postman

I want to send a post to my json server in order to change the data base (I want to add information to it with "post"). When I do it, the json server add a section with an id presented with the next integer, but without all the things I want to add to it. There is no error message and all is like working but it's not. I did research on google to solve my problem but all the tutorial presenting the postman system for begginers nervers has this problem and all the field are correctly expressed in the tutorial (but not in my case!). I do all of this because I am building a REST api

This is how I start my json server with the Windows10 cmd(and I connect with postman using localhost:3000)

```
json-server --watch db.json
```

and this is my db.json:

```
    {
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "json-server",
      "author": "typicode"
    }
  ],
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "body": "some comment",
      "postId": 1
    }
  ],
  "profile": {
    "name": "typicode"
  }
}
```

And this is the code I have when I start the json server

```
     \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading db.json
  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:3000/posts
  http://localhost:3000/comments
  http://localhost:3000/profile

  Home
  http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: Please provide the resource endpoint and POST body you are sending through postman.

Comment: I  send this in the POST body : 
{
    "name":"Henry",
    "password"="pass123"
}

... and I don't understand wath you describe with "resource endpoint" can you name the precise file I have to present? I send it to the adress http://localhost:3000/posts

Sorry for the lack of accuracy in my informatics vocabulary

Comment: Resource endpoint is exactly as you described :)  localhost:3000/posts

Based on your provided POST body, you are sending invalid JSON.
{ "name":"Henry", "password"="pass123" }
should be...
{ "name":"Henry", "password":"pass123" }

no '=' character.

Comment: I copied and pasted the  { "name":"Henry", "password":"pass123" } and i tried to post it but I have the same problem. It is only adding {"id": 19} to my localhost:3000/post

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your Postman request?

Comment: How do we share the screenshot? Do you have discord????

Comment: Check to ensure you have your postman body type set correctly. Choose "raw" and select "JSON" from the dropdown on the right.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x5uOw858KIASYzhvCvODnhnX2KljkWLx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also ensure that Headers "Content-Type" is set to "application/json"

Comment: I hope this was of help to you and you were able to resolve the issue. If so please accept my answer below :) Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the following options are set in postman:

1. Check that you have Header set "Content-Type: application/json"
2. Ensure the body type is set to "raw" and type dropdown is set to "JSON"
3. POST body must be valid JSON.